# play 2.0 - setter on domain object not called in test

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In play 1.2.4 when you extended your test class with UnitTest the setters of domain object where called during the test, in play 2.0 they are not called (see example below).
What am I doing wrong?

Example :

```
@Embeddable
public class Amount {

    public static Amount zero() {
        Amount amount = new Amount();
        //setValue should be called here by play framework
        amount.value = BigDecimal.ZERO; 
        return amount;
    }

    public static Amount of(double amount) {
        Amount result = new Amount();
        //setValue should be called here by play framework
        result.value = BigDecimal.valueOf(amount);
        return result;
    }

    public BigDecimal value;

    public void setValue(BigDecimal value) {
        this.value = rounded(value);
    }

    public Amount add(Amount amount) {
        Amount result = new Amount();
        result.value = rounded(this.value.add(amount.value));
        return result;
    }

    private BigDecimal rounded(BigDecimal aNumber){
        return aNumber.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Amount other = (Amount) obj;
        if (value == null) {
            if (other.value != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Amount [value=" + value + "]";
    }

}
```

test in 1.2.4 succeeds => setValue is called on Amount

```
public class AmountTest extends UnitTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToRoundedHalfEven(){
        Assertions.assertThat(Amount.of(1.055)).isEqualTo(Amount.of(1.06));
        Assertions.assertThat(Amount.of(1.025)).isEqualTo(Amount.of(1.02));
        Assertions.assertThat(Amount.of(1.016)).isEqualTo(Amount.of(1.02));
        Assertions.assertThat(Amount.of(1.011)).isEqualTo(Amount.of(1.01));
        Assertions.assertThat(Amount.of(1.010)).isEqualTo(Amount.of(1.01));
    }


}
```

test in 2.0 fails because setValue is not called

```
public class AmountTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToRoundedHalfEven(){
         running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   assertThat(Amount.of(1.055)).isEqualTo(Amount.of(1.06));
                   assertThat(Amount.of(1.025)).isEqualTo(Amount.of(1.02));
                   assertThat(Amount.of(1.016)).isEqualTo(Amount.of(1.02));
                   assertThat(Amount.of(1.011)).isEqualTo(Amount.of(1.01));
                   assertThat(Amount.of(1.010)).isEqualTo(Amount.of(1.01));
               }
            });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play 2 does not have the bytecode enhancement that Play 1 did and does not automatically call setters like this.  If you don't want to write getters and setters you can use project lombok (you'll need to set it up in a subproject though.  Search the Play Google Groups forum for info on setting up Lombok).  This will save you from having to implement the setX method, but you'll still have to call it instead of accessing the property directly.